# Using Left Joins in HQL on 3 Tables

Tags: hql

I have three tables A B and C.  Now i want to execute this sql query in HQL:

```
select * from A as a 
left join 
B as b 
on 
a.id = b.id 
left join 
C as c 
on 
b.type=c.type;
```

Need help in writing equivalent HQL. I tried with this HQL...

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
    "FROM A as a 
     LEFT JOIN 
     B as b 
     on 
     a.id=b.id 
     LEFT JOIN 
     C as c 
     on 
     b.type=c.type");
```

This query is throwing exception .....

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: LEFT near
>   line 1, column 23 [FROM com.admin.A as a LEFT JOIN B as b where
>   a.Id=b.Id LEFT JOIN C as c where b.type=c.type]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getQuery(SessionFactoryImpl.java:414)

I also tried with "with" and "on" clauses instead of where...I get the same unexpected token on "on" or "with"

exception qith ON .....

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: ON near line
>   1, column 41 [FROM com.admin.A as a LEFT JOIN B as b on a.Id=b.Id LEFT
>   JOIN C as c onb.type=c.type] at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:74)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:127)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:83)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getQuery(SessionFactoryImpl.java:414)

I also tried with "with" clauses instead of where...I get the same unexpected token on or "with"

exception qith WITH .....

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: ON near line
>   1, column 41 [FROM com.admin.A as a LEFT JOIN B as b on a.Id=b.Id LEFT
>   JOIN C as c onb.type=c.type] at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:74)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:127)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:83)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getQuery(SessionFactoryImpl.java:414)

Please help.

Answer (score 22):

I suppose you've already defined all the needed associations in your configuration. If so, in HQL it would look like this:

```
from A as a left join a.B as b left join b.C as c
```

There is no "ON" statement in HQL, hibernate does automatically based on your mappings and defined Associations.

Pay attention to **a.B** and **b.C**.

You refer to B and C based on already defined aliases a & c.

Comment: how would we store the data into a list in this case?

Answer (score 8):

Use this query

```
from A as a
left join fetch a.B as b 
left join fetch b.C as c
```