# HQL : Multiple inner joins in HQL queries

Tags: hibernate, join, orm, hql

I have many entities in my project , and i want to retrieve the data from multiple entities by using HQL query. In HQL query i try to use JOINS to retrieve the data from Entities , but it generate the exception when the code is executed. Following is the exception :

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT s.id, s.name, s.url, s.uuid, s.createdBy , t.id , u.id , u.name FROM com.insonix.qrata.models.Site s INNER JOIN s.topics t INNER JOIN User u  WHERE lower(s.name) LIKE lower(:name)  AND s.createdBy IN (:created_by) AND u.id = s.createdBy]
```

Following is the Query :

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.url, s.uuid, s.createdBy , t.id , u.id , u.userinfo.firstname , u.userinfo.lastname FROM Site s INNER JOIN s.topics t INNER JOIN User u WHERE lower(s.name) LIKE lower(:name)  AND s.createdBy IN (:created_by) AND u.id = s.createdBy
```

Following is my Entities :

```
public class CommonEntity {
-------------------
 private Long createdBy;
 private String uuid;
------------------------
}

public class Site extends CommonEntity{
 private long id;
 private String url;
 private String name;
 private Category category;
 private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(0);
  ---------------------------
}

public class Topic extends CommonEntity{
 private int id;
 private List<Site> sites = new ArrayList<Site>(0);
----------------------------------- 
}

public class User extends CommonEntity
 private long id;
 private UserInfo userinfo;
--------------------------------
}

public class UserInfo extends CommonEntity{
 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Path expected error shows that hibernate is trying to find an association or mapping b/w User and Site. For hibernate to join entities, you must have defined associations. There is no ON clause in hibernate hence in above query how you would specify, where to join 'INNER JOIN User u ON ???', (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669051/830945)

You can achieve results required like this

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.url, s.uuid, s.createdBy, t.id , u.id , u.userinfo.firstname , u.userinfo.lastname FROM Site s, User u INNER JOIN s.topics t WHERE lower(s.name) LIKE lower(:name)  AND s.createdBy IN (:created_by) AND u.id = s.createdBy
```

Comment: how to achive this `User u INNER JOIN s.topics` because user and sites have no relation.

Comment: No! Now you are fetching data from two tables, Site s and User u, by 'FROM Site s, User u' and then joining Site`s 'topics' as 't' by 'INNER JOIN s.topics t' and narrowing results by defining WHERE clause on user`s properties...