# How can I convert a SQL query with a derived table to HQL?

Tags: sql, hql

```
SELECT * 
FROM visitdetails vd 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, VisitID 
     FROM claimfilelist GROUP BY VisitID) cf ON cf.visitid = vd.Id 
LEFT JOIN claimfilelist cf1 ON cf1.id = cf.id
```

I have this SQL query. How can I convert it to HQL?

Comment: Hive Query Language or Hibernate Query Language?

Comment: hibernate query language

Answer (score 1):

The [HQL-documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-subqueries.html) says that subqueries are only allowed in `SELECT` and `WHERE`. So, my first step is to move the subquery to the `WHERE`-clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM visitdetails vd
  LEFT JOIN claimfilelist cf ON cf.visitid = vd.id
WHERE cf.id IS NULL OR cf.id = (
  SELECT max(cfInner.id)
  FROM claimfilelist cfInner
  WHERE cfInner.visitId = vd.id
)
```

Depending on your Hibernate - version you might need to change the joins. I am not sure if the query works, but you could give the approach a try.

Comment: Does hql supports 'on' condition for left join?

Comment: " LEFT JOIN claimfilelist cf ON cf.visitid = vd.id" Is it possible to join table with this 'on' condition in hql ?

Comment: "org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 87 [from com.safecare.cms.modal.VisitdetailsNew vd left join ClaimFileListForDateEntry cf on cf.visitid= vd.id where cf.id is null or cf.id=(select max(cfInner.id) from com.safecare.cms.modal.ClaimFileListForDateEntry cfInner where cfInner.visitid = vd.id]"

Comment: I think it depends on the Hibernate - version. The usual way is to use relations that are defined in your entities, but I don't know your entities. This gives an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470876/using-left-joins-in-hql-on-3-tables. If you are not used to HQL you can start with a minimal query and add step by step what you need. You could do 1. query all rows from visitdetails, 2. add the join and 3. add the subquery.

Comment: Actually,this is not my original query. i posted a portion of my query here.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? What is not your original query? Do you mean the portion in your comment? And what's the difference that it makes? Is it about joining. According to the documentation, the subquery in the `FROM`-clause won't work in HQL as I mentioned in the answer.